# pyodbc/sqlalchemy - read each column in the table using pd.read_sql_query. Pass variable through the query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I want to pass a variable 'single_column' through pd.read_sql_query in loop:

```
for single_column in columns_list:    
    df_trial_queries = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT single_column FROM dw.db.table;",db_cnxn)
```

I tried to use something like this:

```
for single_column in columns_list:    
        df_trial_queries = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT %(column_name)s FROM dw.db.table;",db_cnxn,params = {'column_name':single_column})
```

No luck at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "paremeterize" table or column names in SQL (SQL allows to "parameterize" [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) only), but you can easily do it on Python level:

```
In [25]: single_column = 'col1'

In [52]: table = 'dw.db.table'

In [53]: "SELECT {} FROM {}".format(single_column, table)
Out[53]: 'SELECT col1 FROM dw.db.table'
```

or in your case:

```
df_trial_queries = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT {} FROM dw.db.table".format(single_column), db_cnxn)
```

NOTE: it's very inefficient way! I'm sure there is a better way to achieve your goals, but you would have to shed some light on what are you going to achieve using this loop...

Comment: from each of the column that is read from server into dataframe, I want to run some data profiling and descriptive statistics, then save into csv file. I am doing that because table has 52 million rows and 80 columns

Comment: @dsl1990, can `some data profiling and descriptive statistics` be done on the SQL server side?

Comment: I can do that, but there are many tables and I will have to write sql queries. I wanted to make automated loops for this. I am marking this as correct answer but can you edit it, if I have to pass two such variables instead of one